# EditText going beyond the window bound when keyboard comes in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

In my manifest.xml I have set this to my current `Activity`.

```
<activity
        android:name=".StockAdjustment"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
        android:label="@string/Metrix"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
    </activity>
```

my problem is when the keyboard appears my `EditText` going up too much. It beyond the view's upper bound and cant even see what I am typing. 
No matter whatever I put for `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` the same result comes.

Please help me.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

[image: This is my layout]

**UPDATE 2**

```
<ScrollView
        style="@style/ScrollViewBase.Normal.Vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:isScrollContainer="false">
```

Comment: can you share your layout?

Comment: @EnamulHaque I added an image of my layout. Can you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achived this my changing the structure of my layout.xml. 
I changed my layout xml file into this

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/LinearBase.Normal.Vertical" >

            <ScrollView
                style="@style/ScrollViewBase.Normal.Vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                tools:isScrollContainer="false">
                <LinearLayout style="@style/LinearBase.Normal.Vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/table_layout"
                        style="@style/LinearBase.Normal.Vertical"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/TextViewBase.Title"
                            android:tag="SCREEN_LABEL"></TextView>

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/TextViewBase.Emphasis"
                            android:tag="SCREEN_TIP"></TextView>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/serialList"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

            <include layout="@layout/stock_adjustment_menu_bar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Previously, my `Scrollview` is shrinking/paning, then the `ListView`going up and I cant see the content inside the `ScrollView`. After I changed the layout structure, my whole content(Textviews,EditTexts adding by the code and ListView) is inside a single `ScrollView`. So shrinking/paning happens by considering the whole content of inside the `Scrollview`.

**Make sure to disable the scrolling for parent view when touch the `ListView`**

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan|adjustResize"`

Also, if you have a `ScrollView` in your layout, add `android:isScrollContainer="false"` to your `ScrollView`

Comment: I added this as well. But nothing changed. Still going too high

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: android:isScrollContainer="false" this should be added in manifest?

Comment: `android:isScrollContainer="false"` should be added as a parameter to your `ScrollView` in your layout file, **not** in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: in my activity layout I have already set this tools:isScrollContainer=false

Comment: Have you tried with `android:isScrollContainer="false"` instead of `tools:isScrollContainer="false"`?

Comment: yeas just now I checked but still same :(

Comment: IS there any way to disable the view pushing up if the EditText is not covering by the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and also set the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to parent layout element.

```
<ScrollView
    style="@style/ScrollViewBase.Normal.Vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:isScrollContainer="false">
```

Comment: I am not sure why still it same. Nothing changes :(